# Ask for valid attributes in JSON:API spec

Tags: json-api

I want to use [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/format/) for my new REST APIs. The specification sounds good and everything is fine. The only thing i am missing is a way to ask for the valid attributes for an entity.

If there is no entity yet i found no documented possibility to see what attributes i need to create a new one. Does anyone have the same problem or a good solution to fix this gap?

**Example**

***Request to get the list of articles***

```
GET /articles HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
```

***Response (with zero articles)***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles"
  },
  "data": []
}
```

***=> Here i am missing a call the retrieve available attributes for a new article entity <=***

***Request to create an article***

```
POST /photos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "New Article" <= i have to know this attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) does not include a type system. This is one of the limitations compared to [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/). But JSON:API could be combined with additional standards to address that requirements.

For example you could provide an [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) interface (formerly Swagger) to provide machine-readable type information and documentation for your entire API.

As an alternative to OpenAPI you could use [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) to describe the interface of each resources. OpenAPI supports a subset of JSON Schema. So both could be nicely combined.

Your question partly implies that you could derive a schema of a resource based on a resource object. I would not recommend to do so:

- A resource object may not contain all fields. Some files may be hidden by due to using a [Sparse Fieldset](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets). Or the server may not include all fields by default.
- An attribute may support multiple values. E.g. `null` may be a valid value even though the attribute is a string for one resource object.
- An attribute may need to follow validation rules additionally to having the same type. E.g. a date attribute may be encoded as the string `"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"` in JSON. But that doesn't mean that all strings are valid values for that attribute.